# Getting coordinate vector in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

I know how to get the coordinate vector of single matrices by just joining them and doing a gauss jordan. But these are a 2x2, I don't know how to go about this, apparently no elimination can take place just by looking at it. Help me out;

[image]

Comment: Try writing $v$ in terms of $e_1,\ldots,e_4$.

Comment: All you're being asked to do is find numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $$a\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}+b\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0\cr}$$ $+c\pmatrix{0&0\cr1&0\cr}+d\pmatrix{0&0\cr0&1\cr}=\pmatrix{-1&-5\cr-5&-1\cr}$. If you know how to multiply a matrix by a number, and how to add two matrices, you should be able to get a handle on this. Can you do those things?

Comment: If this question is what it looks like (potentially it is homework for credit) then the first person you need to ask for hints is your teacher.

Comment: Why does the answer area only have 2 boxes?

Comment: i don't know why it only has 2 boxes. Thanks for answering

Comment: Thankyou very much Gerry Myerson for the hint